# Can't open syntax.vim error when using vimrc

Tags: centos, vim, vimrc

When I try to open my `.bashrc` file. then it shows these lines:

```
Errordetected while processing /etc/vimrc:
line 45:
E848: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I go to the `/etc/vimrc` file , it shows `syntax on` line 45. I've installed the OS three times and it always shows the same error.

Comment: Would be nice to see the whole .vimrc. Can you make a gist or a pastebin?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/syntax.vim` exist? If so, is it readable?

Comment: No, it does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is trying to use a file for lexical highlighting. The file does not exist at the place where vim is looking for it.

At this point, you can do any one of the following:

- Remove the reference to syntax in /etc/vimrc
- Look for the syntax file on your server (e.g. `find / -name syntax.vim`) and copy or symlink that file to the directory where vim is looking
- download a syntax file, e.g. from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/download.php)
- create a syntax file - there's documentation at [vimdoc.sourceforge.net](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html)

Answer (score 3):

Vim expects to find its installation files (eg help system, definitions for syntax highlighting) in a particular place but can run without many of them. It's possible that while you can run Vim, it cannot locate these installation files.

Vim will try several methods to locate these files but if you have a unusual installation then they won't be found.

If you can access the help system, read these topics: `:help $VIM` and `:help $VIMRUNTIME`. You'll likely not find them with your current configuration, therefore read versions on the Web, eg [:help $VIM](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#$VIM) and [:help $VIMRUNTIME](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#$VIMRUNTIME).

I suspect that you can solve your problem by correctly setting one or both of the VIM and VIMRUNTIME environment variables.

You might discover that the `vim` binary and runtime files exist in disparate directory trees and that you'll need to hunt for the runtime files below some path, eg: `find /path -type d -name 'vim[0-9]*'`

### An Example

I rely on a Vim instance that is bundled with the Sun Studio development package, which our SysAdmin has provided via a remote mount. The `vim` binary is located at `/remote/sunstudio12/SUNWspro/contrib/vim/bin/vim` (eg `which vim`) and the runtime files are located in `/remote/sunstudio12/SUNWspro/contrib/vim/share/vim/vim63`.

I had a similar problem to yours. Firstly, I tried exporting `VIM=/remote/sunstudio12/SUNWspro/contrib/vim`, but that didn't work. Separately, I tried exporting `VIMRUNTIME=/remote/sunstudio12/SUNWspro/contrib/vim/share/vim/vim63`, which works correctly (while VIM remains unset). `VIMRUNTIME` should point to a directory containing files such as `menu.vim`, `scripts.vim` and directories such as `colors`, `doc`, `syntax` etc (possibly version-dependant, YMMV).

I also modified my `PATH` to locate the `vim` binary, however, you can successfully run the binary already.

#### (Updated...)

I revisited my shell environment settings for the above, and found that exporting `VIM=/remote/sunstudio12/SUNWspro/contrib/vim/share/vim` (and unsetting `VIMRUNTIME`) also worked -- my initial experiments with setting `VIM` were misguided. The location pointed to by `VIM` contains a directory, `vim63`, containing the run-time files that I need.

I still rely on `PATH` to locate the `vim` binary.

Answer (score 0):

The missing file is not a syntax definition, it is the Vimscript implementation of the `:syntax on` command. Without it, there will be no syntax highlighting in Vim.

That file comes with Vim; your installation must have become corrupted. Try re-installing. Also, Vim 7.0 is from 2006 and *very* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution, it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your .vimrc that you aren't specifying where vim should look for syntax.vim. eg:

```
set rtp+=/usr/local/vim/
set rtp+=/usr/local/vim/runtime/
let $VIMRUNTIME="/usr/local/vim/runtime/"
```

If you copied your .vimrc from macos you may have something like the above, used to work around the conflict between Apple-installed and Brew-installed vim.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after reinstalling my homebrew installed vim on my mac. I fixed it by symlinking the `share/vim` folder from the install to `/usr/local/share/vim` like so:

```
latest_vim="$(ls -rtd /usr/local/Cellar/vim/* | tail -n1)"
ln -sf "$latest_vim/share/vim" /usr/local/share/vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after using "export VIM=vim" in my shell startup script. I had copied someone else's from the internet, so my VIM variable wasn't set properly. Removed the line from .kshrc (most would be using .bashrc probably) and logged completely out and in again.

Answer (score -1):

If you did not install `vim-runtime`, you will get such error.